# Best way to use sed to replace a value with wildcard, in multiple files on unix

Tags: sed

I do a lot of little one-liners - just wondering if there's a better way - mind you, i do not really mind this way, just wondering.

Problem: replace `set timeout whatever` with `set timeout 10` in multiple expect scripts:

```
mkdir .1111
for i in sssh*; do
    echo $i
    cat $i | sed "s:set timeout.*:set timeout 10:g" > .1111/$i
done
mv .1111/* .
rmdir .1111
```

If you have improvements, please post them.
I bet it can be done better in perl, but I am not there ;)

Comment: If you know `find`, it can be very good at generating the equivalent to the for loop with much more flexibility, but it is quite complex to learn.

Comment: You may want to put double quotes round your `"${i}"` filename arguments incase they contain spaces.

Comment: Given that you aren't checking if anything went wrong, you could streamline to: `sed -i -e 's/\(set timeout\).*/\1 10/' sssh*`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) suggests several improvements.

Comment: I'm guessing that `mv .1111 .` is a typo. That command does nothing, and will give an error saying that `.1111` and `./.1111` are the same thing. Did you mean `mv .1111/* .`, perhaps?

Comment: Correct! mv .111/* . 
;) Thx for catching that! fixed!

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom would be something like:

```
find . -type f -name "sssh*" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's:set timeout.*:set timeout 10:g'
```

You can tweak the arguments to `find` depending on the locations of the target files.

Answer (score 0):

In all of the find and sed examples you guys gave, i see how the replace happens, but i do not see how the file actually gets changed. I guess I never understood that sed will actually edit the file and write it back? I always used it with a | ,  hence having to handle temp file and whatever....